# Unable to start ASP.NET Core Web API hosted in a Windows service

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi

I have built an ASP.NET Core Web API project and I'm trying to host it in a Windows service.

**Program.cs**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureWebHost(webBuilder =>
                     {
                         webBuilder.UseUrls("https://localhost:5000;http://*:5000;https://*:5001")  ;
                         webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                      })
               .UseWindowsService();
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: There issue should happen when you develop the application, instead after publishing, right? From the second error message: "Unable to resolve server for type `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer` ..." we can see that it unable to resolve the service. please check your application, might be you want to use some services but not register them in the StartUp.cs file. Please check your code and the relates Dependency injection in your application.

Comment: I gave up this way of using the host, instead now i am using Kestrel as a server. The question can be closed